# How to access a variable in a function from another function in Django

Tags: django

So, I'm trying to access the variable `store` in `get_queryset()` from `get_context_data()`. I though I can deal with that by using a global variable. But it didn't work too. Is there any other way to do that?

```
class StoreDetailView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(store) # an error happens
        ...


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StoreDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['store'] = Store.objects.filter(domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey'])
    context['store'] = get_object_or_404(Store, domainKey=self.kwargs['store_domainKey'])

        store = context['store']
        ...
```

Comment: Why don't you access the query inside get_queryset?

Comment: @Lemayzeur The query starts from a value in kwargs. So, whatever I do in the middle, it needs to start in `get_context_data`, and needs to be done in `get_queryset()` to use pagination.

Comment: You have access to `self.kwargs['store_domainKey']` in get_queryset,, no need to do it in context_Data

Comment: actually, your `get_queryset` should handle the `queryset` at all, `get_context_data` is only to send more data to templates via `context`

Comment: Since I'm new to Django, I don't even know what I'm doing right now lol. The more I write, the more confused I am. I need to study more to figure out what each function is actually supposed to do. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `self`, to make it a class variable

```
# set variable
self.store = context['store']

# get variable
print(self.store)
```

Comment: am I wrong or `this` doesn't exist in python? you meant `self`

Comment: It causes an error "`name 'this' is not defined`". Why is that?

Comment: @Lemayzeur `self` also shows an error `'StoreDetailView' object has no attribute 'store'` as well

Comment: @Jay yes use `self`. thanks @Lemayzeur for the update

Comment: `get_queryset` method executing before `get_context_data`  that's why you are getting error means you are trying to get value of variable which is not defined yet

Comment: so you cannot set varible in `get_context_data` and access it in `get_queryset `, reverse can be possible.